# How To cache my index?

Tags: php, caching

How can I cache my PHP index page to the `/cache` folder so it loads faster? Is this the preferred method to improve load times, or is there a better approach?

Comment: I'm sorry, this question is not comprehensible.

Comment: postParser : grammatical and spelling errors threshold exceeded, processing next message.

Answer (score 0):

You may find interesting the follow links

[PHP accelerator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP_accelerator)

[List of PHP accelerators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_PHP_accelerators)

Answer (score 0):

Fastest method is to cache on the client. After that the different methods will yield variable results depending on the nature of the application and the network. But without any more information its impossible to tell.

You might try:

- checking for effective caching of static content
- eliminating performance bottlenecks from your code
- using a template system
- using a caching reverse proxy
- caching output using php code
- using an opcode cache

What have you tried? What analysis of the system have you done? What are the constraints?

Not a very meaningful question.

C.